# How to obtain Cauchy Distribution in Fortran?

Tags: fortran

I have to generate n pseudo-random numbers in a standard cauchy distribution in Fortran. Now I know that there is an Intel MKL routine 'vdrngcauchy' but I need to run the code on an IBM Power 9 system and so far I haven't found an alternative to MKL. Can someone suggest a Fortran library that will do the job on an IBM power 9 system?

Comment: What did you try sofar, show some code. Did you google ? a google for "Cauchy Distribution in Fortran?" would probably give some hits.

Comment: Welcome. Please use tag [tag:fortran] for Fortran questions and take the Welcome [tour] to see how to use this sit. [ask] will also be useful. Asking for an external library is off-topic here.